# Hardware interrupts

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

I have a beginner's question: Let's say I start Eclipse and the splash screen comes up. When I move my mouse a lot during startup, do I cause a hardware interrupt with every movement that makes the cpu save the current state of the eclipse loading process, recalculates the mouse position and so on and then restore the loading process? So every movement causes the cpu to save the current stack and registers and so on and then later restore it?

Comment: In general, yes, although there are a lot of device- and platform-specific details as to how interrupts might be batched and later delivered to the processor. For instance, your mouse is likely a USB device, so the message generated by your mouse to indicate movement goes through many protocol layers before it ultimately gets acted upon. Do you have a more detailed question?

Comment: pretty much, yes. the fact that violently scrubbing your mouse around the screen DOESN'T totally hose performance on (most) machines just shows that those kinds of hardware interrupt handlers are (and have to be) very efficient code.

Comment: Back in the 8-bit days, moving the mouse could be CPU-intensive. Since the mid 1980's, not so much.

Comment: @All: well, I dont really have a more in-depth question yet, I'm afraid. I was just bazzled a bit... I mean, I know how many GHz and how much RAM modern computers have, but still... it's kinda crazy... Thanks for your replies!

Comment: If you think that's crazy, imagine how many network and disk interrupts are going on as you download your pron, movies and TV shows in the bakground with your BitTorrent client:)